# How to take image from camera without saving it in SDCard?

Tags: android, android-camera

If you are using whatsapp , check that it upload profile picture by camera without saving it in SDcard,
How can we implement that ?

Comment: your foto-object exists on runtime, so you can use it out of the memory. else you can save the photo at other places.

Comment: So you want to upload the image from camera, or just use it within your app?

Comment: I want to upload the image from camera, but without save it in SDCard

Answer (score 1):

```
1.    whatsapp does store your image .
```

Notice that when the phone is not connected to internet , it stores the it in the phone , and may be enqueue it to some kind of handler  and then probably set the new profile picture as soon when connected to internet .

```
2. Not saving the image & transferring it somewhere else
```

1] Request for permission

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

</manifest ... >
```

2] Using Intent to take the photo &  Calling your code :

```
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, ANY_ACTION_CODE);
```

3][Optional for you] Viewing the photo (by setting it to ImageView)

```
private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app opens camera and calls Camera.takePicture(), it receives the captured image in Jpeg as byte array. You can do whatever you want with these bytes - write to local storage, send to the cloud.

You cannot avoid going through sdcard if you use camera capture intent.